# Show/Hide different Divs with button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to jQuery and I'm struggling to let the table row collapse and expand. The rows are under different rows with buttons next to them. Can someone please help me to specify which row must collapse onclick.  Here is my code.

### jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
            $('.td1').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

### HTML first row

```
@foreach (var item in Model1)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @*<a href="javascript:hideElem(@item.OrderNumber)" onclick="hideElem(@item.OrderNumber)">HClick here</a>*@
            @*<a href="" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd">SClick here</a>*@
            <button id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd">ADD</button>
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransactionDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lines)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderedTotal)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProcessedTotal)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
}
```

### HTML Second Row

```
<td>
    <button id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd">ADD</button>
</td>

@foreach (var item2 in Model2)
{
    if (item2.Order == item.OrderNumber)
    {
        <tr class="rowClass td1" id="td1" style="background-color:rgb(217,237,247); padding:0px;">
            <td style="width:20px"></td>

            <td>
                <div>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.PickNo)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <div style="float:left">
                    Ended:
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.PickEndDate)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.PickEndTime)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <img src="~/Icons/WAGIconPDF.PNG" width="20" height="20" /> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.InvNo)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <img src="~/Icons/WAGIconWarehouse1.PNG" width="20" height="20" />   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.WarehouseCode)
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a collapsible panel

Comment: You creating invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes (all your buttons have `id="btnAdd"`). You need to use a class name and relative selectors to get the associated elements you want to toggle

Comment: thanks alot guys ive changed my jquery the only problem i have now is that if i click on one of the buttons all the rows below that collapse cuz im using nextuntil() is there a way that i can collapse the rows that match the order number

Comment: new Jquery

     $(function () {
         $("td[colspan=3]").find("p").hide();
         $("table").click(function (event) {
             event.stopPropagation();
             var $target = $(event.target);
             $target.closest("tr").nextUntil().find("p").slideToggle();

         });
     });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got it 
jQuery Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function () {
    $("td[colspan=3]").find("p").hide();
    $("table").click(function (event) {

        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        $target.closest("tr").nextUntil(".parent").find("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

AND THEN MY HTML CODE

```
  <table class="table table-bordered noSpace" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

    <tr>
        <th>

        </th>
        <th>
            Order Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Transaction Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Company
        </th>
        <th>
            Lines
        </th>
        <th>
            Ordered Total
        </th>
        <th>
            Processed Total
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>

        <th>
            Info
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model1)
    {

        <tr class="parent">

            <td>

                <span>Click</span>

            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransactionDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lines)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderedTotal)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProcessedTotal)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        foreach (var item2 in Model2)
        {

            if (item2.Order == item.OrderNumber)
            {
                <tr class="NewRows">
                    <td style="width:20px"></td>
                    <td>
                            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.PickNo)</p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="4">
                            <p style="float:left">
                                Ended:

                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.PickEndDate)
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.PickEndTime)
                            </p>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                            <p><img src="~/Icons/WAGIconPDF.PNG" width="20" height="20" /> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.InvNo)</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <p><img src="~/Icons/WAGIconWarehouse1.PNG" width="20" height="20" />@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.WarehouseCode)</p>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }

        }
    }

</table>
```